# GET request preflight fails in browser (using React framework)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, cors, preflight

I'm trying to send an API GET request with the Authorizer header. The request works fine with curl and Postman: [Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sGup.png)

If I send the GET request without the Authorizer header it works as expected but as soon as I add the header it sends the preflight OPTIONS and it fails.

This is my code:

```js
function GetData() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("load", () => {
      console.log(req.responseText);
    });
    req.open(
      "GET",
      "https://qrdc992lul.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/account"
    );
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    req.withCredentials = true;
    req.send();
  }
```

I get the following response:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://qrdc992lul.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/account'
>   from origin 'https://ogx7o.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Response header:

> content-length: 42 content-type: application/json date: Tue, 04 Feb
>   2020 13:09:37 GMT status: 403 via: 1.1
>   37adc88abfddc6deef6672a655706cd4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>   x-amz-apigw-id: HX36rHhxDoEFXxw= x-amz-cf-id:
>   hgFvoQwvQ96Uge3ciwwvd41RCNyX1oZyVydPIyXqPQxe0aAeklM2WA== x-amz-cf-pop:
>   MAN50-C3 x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
>   x-amzn-requestid: 4383a667-e30b-44fb-ac3b-bd532e99f1d4 x-cache: Error
>   from cloudfront

I had a read about CORS headers and preflight and I kinda figured that the issue is that there's no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header but don't know how to resolve the issue.

I have added the code snippet to Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-river-ogx7o

API is API Gateway Lambda Proxy integration.

I'm still learning React and I have the feeling I'm sending the request wrong. What am I missing?

UPDATE:
[API Gateway is set to return the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdfre.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Try removing the `req.withCredentials = true;` line

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In case anyone finds this question later I solved the following way:

- As preflight send OPTIONS request this also needs an API endpoint. So you need both GET and OPTIONS, and set up method response headers for both.

  /account
  GET
  OPTIONS

API Gateway -> Resource -> Actions -> Enable CORS guides you through what to do

- Code was incorrect. As suggested by Anurag Hazra, req.withCreditentials = true; was removed

Answer (score -1):

In your back end, you will need to authorize the header you are adding
using [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)
(This is for the header "Authorization" you are adding)